# Translate property not working on div

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've been trying to center both horizontally and vertically a specific `div`, and I got the vertical part to center, just not the horizontal part.

I'm using `translate(-50%, -50%)`, which should be centering  in a center, but is not working...

The part that says *"Or login to your acccount"*  is the part  I'm trying to vertically center.

[Link to the site](http://niil.me/login/login.php)

**Relevant CSS:**

```css
.logindiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do 2 things:

- add a wrapper(this will be the green `div`), let's call `login-wrap`, and give it this properties:

```css
.login-wrap {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}
```

- change `relative` to `absolute` here

```css
.logindiv {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think to use a wrapper! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margins for horizontal center positioning

```
.logindiv {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

transform is working. Try this one. You have to define your transform style for all the browsers.

```
.logindiv {

    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-23%, -38%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-23%, -38%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-23%, -38%) /* safari*/
    width: 382px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original code:

```
.logindiv {
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

By changing the position to absolute, you can move the logindiv around with the transform: translate() (which does X first, then Y)

I chose 60%, -70% as that looked centered with the left on my screen, but mess around with it. This was the only way I could find to let it resize the same way as the welcome text on the left.

New code:

```
.logindiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(60%, -70%); 
}
```